# Adding a farm solution to my home page have affected all the pages inside my library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, farm

I have created the following farm solution, to enable navigating the term store :-

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.QueryString["TreeField"])
                && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.QueryString["TreeValue"]))
            {
                response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?TreeField={1}&TreeValue={2}",
                    SPContext.Current.ListItem.ParentList.DefaultViewUrl,
                    request.QueryString["TreeField"],
                    request.QueryString["TreeValue"]));
            }
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.QueryString["TreeField"]))
            {
                response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?TreeField={1}",
                    SPContext.Current.ListItem.ParentList.DefaultViewUrl,
                    request.QueryString["TreeField"]));
            }
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

So I went to the library home page and I Inserted the Web Part, but I have noted that the term-store navigation is now working on all the library pages which do not have the web part added?
So I am confused on how the web part is working for all the library pages, although I have added it to the home page only?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the "library home page"?  What specific page did you modify and in what specific location, and how did you modify it ( edit a file by hand, via the Web interface, through a deployment, etc )?

Comment: the home page is the default page which opens when you call the sub site. and i have added the web part manually to the home page , by the browser. i click on edit >> insert >> web part >> custom,, then i select the web part which i have created using Visual Studio ...